Ray class field and its conductor
Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be an ideal of the ring of integers of a number field $K$ and $S$ is a subset of the real places, then the ray class group of
$\mathfrak{m}$ and $S$ is the quotient group
$$I^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}$$
where $I^{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the group of fractional ideals co-prime to $\mathfrak{m}$, and the ray $P^{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the group of principal ideals generated by elements $\alpha$ with $\alpha\equiv1\bmod \mathfrak{m}$ that are positive at the places of $S$. Let $K^{\mathfrak{m}}$ be the ray class field of $K$ correspond to the ray class group by Class Field Theory and we have that
$$I^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}\cong \mathrm{Gal}(K^{\mathfrak{m}}/K).$$
We know that if $\mathfrak{m}\mid \mathfrak{m}'$, then $K^{\mathfrak{m}}\subset K^{\mathfrak{m}'}$(Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, page 397).
Questions: $(1)$ If $\mathfrak{m}\neq \mathfrak{m}'$, can it happen that $K^{\mathfrak{m}}=K^{\mathfrak{m}'}$ and if it can happen, could someone give me some non-trivial examples?
$(2)$ Let $\mathfrak{f}$ be the conductor of the abelian extension $K^{\mathfrak{m}}/K$, we know that $\mathfrak{f}\mid \mathfrak{m}.$ Do we have that
$$K^{\mathfrak{f}}=K^{\mathfrak{m}}~?$$
$(3)$ Is it true that for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$,
$$\mathfrak{p}\mid\mathfrak{f}\Longleftrightarrow
\mathfrak{p}\mid\mathfrak{m}~?$$

Here's a somewhat silly (but non-trivial) example for (1). Let $K=\mathbb Q$ and $S=\{\infty\}$. Then $I^{(2)}=P^{(2)}$, since every ideal of $\mathbb Z$ that's relatively prime to $2$ has the form $(n)$ for some odd $n$, and if $n<0$, we get the same ideal using $(-n)$. Hence $\mathbb Q^{(2)}=\mathbb Q$. On the other hand, we certainly have  $\mathbb Q^{(1)}=\mathbb Q$. Hence $\mathbb Q^{(2)}=\mathbb Q^{(1)}$.

This is related to the fact that we can have $\mathbf Q(\zeta_m) = \mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$ with $m\not=n$: let $n$ be odd and $m=2n$, so $\zeta_m = -\zeta_n$ Also $\mathbf Q(\zeta_m + \zeta_m^{-1}) = \mathbf Q(\zeta_n +
\zeta_n^{-1})$ when $n$ is odd and $m=2n$. The second example is Joe’s example when  $n=1$.

The same example also provides negative answers to (2) and (3).
